Solve problem with setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build
I am doing a Flutter course on Udemy. Currently, we are building our own widget with this code:
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard(
      {super.key,
      required this.colour,
      this.cardChild = const Placeholder(),
      required this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function? onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress!(),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}

The idea for this widget is currently to implement a function, where the background is marked with another color (i.e. the card is 'selected') when the user clicks on it (i.e. taps on the GestureDetector).
Now, when I use this widget in a StatefulWidget like this

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender? selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                 child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                        ? activeCardBackground
                        : inactiveCardBackground,
                    cardChild: const ChooseGender(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                      text: 'MALE',
                    ),
                    onPress: () => setState(() {
                      selectedGender = Gender.female;
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
// ...
            ]),
          ),
// ...

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I get the error message: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.. This happens if I use the function onPress from the custom created widget ReusableCard.
When I change the code where I use the ReusableCard widget to something like this (i.e. I make a GestureDetector around a ReusableCard and use the function onTap), the function works without any problems.
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => setState(() {
          selectedGender = Gender.male;
        }),
        child: ReusableCard(
          colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
              ? activeCardBackground
              : inactiveCardBackground,
          cardChild: const ChooseGender(
            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
            text: 'MALE',
          ),
          onPress: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),

My question is now why I am getting the error message when I use the GestureDetector within my own widget (and with the use of the function onPress from ReusableCard), but not when I use GestureDetector around a ReusableCard with the function onTap?

If I can use a wrapper, I can use an extra if statement to check the condition, right? :-D You are right. I'll delete my comment to avoid misleading.

The issue is with your ReusableCard definition.
First, when declaring a function variable, it is recommended to provide a complete signature for the function. This is helpful to catch various type related errors.
So instead of
final Function? onPress;

You want
final void Function()? onPress;

Secondly, when you are doing the following:
GestureDetector(
  onTap: onPress!(),
  ...
)

You are immediately invoking the onPress function and passing the result to GestureDetector. What you want to do is simply pass the function itself to GestureDetector, so that the GestureDetector class can control when the function is called.
GestureDetector(
  onTap: onPress,
  ...
)

